# Login with mysql connection

Tags: android, android-layout

When I am filling in the username and password then just clicking login button, an exception:

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

is shown. Logcat output:

```
12-23 11:37:46.677: E/AndroidRuntime(694): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-23 11:37:46.677: E/AndroidRuntime(694): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-23 11:37:46.677: E/AndroidRuntime(694): at com.ar.mydatabaseProject.pack.MydatabaseProjectActivity$1.onClick(MydatabaseProjectActivity.java:117)
12-23 11:37:46.677: E/AndroidRuntime(694): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
12-23 11:37:46.677: E/AndroidRuntime(694): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
12-23 11:37:46.677: E/AndroidRuntime(694): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-23 11:37:46.677: E/AndroidRuntime(694): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-23 11:37:46.677: E/AndroidRuntime(694): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-23 11:37:46.677: E/AndroidRuntime(694): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-23 11:37:46.677: E/AndroidRuntime(694): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-23 11:37:46.677: E/AndroidRuntime(694): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-23 11:37:46.677: E/AndroidRuntime(694): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-23 11:37:46.677: E/AndroidRuntime(694): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-23 11:37:46.677: E/AndroidRuntime(694): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

when am fill in the username and password then just clicking login button that time 
displaying

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

on the Username textbox. So what error here? How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Did u add following permission in your Android Manifest?

It should be above your application tag

If yes send me your code.

Comment: s i already did it..
  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".MydatabaseProject1Activity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says, you cannot run network queries on your main (UI) thread.

When querying the database, do so in a seperate `Thread`. That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to add some more information about your error and code. Your problem lies in the file `MydatabaseProjectActivity.java` line 117.